# Generating all symmetric binary matrices of order up to 7?

Tags: matrix, combinatorics, binary

I want to create all symmetric binary matrix with order up to 7. Can anybody help in creating this?

I want to obtain the subset of all symmetric matrices, with all diagonal entries being zero.

Answer (score 5):

The following code does it for $n=3$; I'll leave it to you to ponder if doing it for $n=7$ is feasible for you.

```
With[{n = 3}, 
     Composition[Transpose[#] + # &, 
                 PadRight[PadLeft[TakeList[#, Range[n - 1, 1, -1]],
                                  {n - 1, n}], {n, n}] &] /@
     Tuples[{0, 1}, Binomial[n, 2]]]
```

[image: results]

For $n=6$, there are $32768$ such matrices, and for $n=7$ there are $2097152$.
In general, there will be $2^\binom{n}{2}=2^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ such matrices.

Comment: Thank you, But it generates all binary matrix. Is there an way for obtaining symmetric matrices only with all diagonal entries zeroes?

Comment: Is it possible to have a direct code for this, instead of performing J.M.'s code first and then the second code, to reduce the computational time and space for larger n.

Comment: @chris, I appreciate it, but the OP should **not have neglected to put in important conditions in the question**, like the zero trace requirement. (Also the matrices are symmetric by construction, so the double `Select[]` was unnecessary.)

Comment: @JM your pre computation of the number of terms is better for the planet. My brute force approach was costly!

Answer (score 4):

For a $n_0^2$ symmetric binary matrix with diagonal==0 there are $n=(n_0^2-n_0)/2$ independent elements. Therefore, we need to create all binary vectors of length n. Then we need to arrange them into `Matrixform`:

```
n0 = 3;
n = (n0^2 - n0)/2;
vecs = Tuples [{0, 1}, {n}];
m0 = Table[0, n0, n0];
mats = (k = 0; m = m0;
     Do[m[[i, j]] = m[[j, i]] = #[[++k]], {i, 1, n0}, {j, i + 1, n0}];
      m) & /@ vecs;
MatrixForm /@ mats
```

[image]

Comment: Timing: For n0=6 it takes 0.84 sec on my machine and for n0=7 it takes already : 71.5 sec.

Answer (score 2):

This way uses `FindInstance` which isn't the most efficient method, but allows you to plug in constraints without too much thinking about how to generate the matrices. Increase the number of solutions (currently max `100`) to get more results if you're trying $n > 3$:

```
matrices = With[{mtx = Array[a, {3, 3}]},
   mtx /. FindInstance[
     (And @@ 
        Map[#[[{2, 1}]] == #[[{1, 2}]] && 0 <= # <= 1 &, 
         Flatten[mtx]]) &&
      (And @@ (# == 0 & /@ Diagonal[mtx])),
     Variables[mtx],
     Integers,
     100
     ]
   ];

MatrixForm /@ matrices
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of an internal, undocumented function to do this.

```
Statistics`Library`VectorToSymmetricMatrix[#, 0, 7]& /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 21]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {3.4017, Null}